# $f(n)=4^n*n$ $g(n)=6^n$, prove or disprove $f \in o(g)$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

$f(n):=4^{n}*n$ and $g(n):=6^n$

so we need to show that $f(n) \leq c g(n)$

I tried to find upper and lower bounds:

$\frac{4^{n}*n}{6^n} = \frac{4^{n}*n}{(3/2)^n4^n} = \frac{n}{(3/2)^n}  $

$\frac{n}{(2)^n}=\frac{n}{(4/2)^n} \leq \frac{n}{(3/2)^n} \leq 
 \frac{n}{(2/2)^n} = n$

However do not think that my approach is useful so any hint would be helpful.

Comment: Do you know what $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(3/2)^n}$ is?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Couldn't I use de l'Hospital? so $\lim \frac{n}{(3/2)^{n}}$ = $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so with de l'hospital: $\lim \frac{1}{n*{(3/2)}^{n-1}} $ = 0 ?

Comment: Yes, you can use l’Hospital’s rule, but you’ve differentiated the denominator incorrectly: $n$ is the variable, so $(3/2)^n$ is an exponential, not a power, and you should get $(3/2)^n\ln(3/2)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for your help!

Comment: You’re welcome!